# How do I install unsettings in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, command-line, downloads

When I try to install through my terminal I get this error:

```
enyel@Alexandria:~$ sudo apt-get unsettings
E: Invalid operation unsettings
enyel@Alexandria:~$ sudo apt-get install unsettings
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I already added the PPA and updated it, can anyone help?

Comment: Is anything else running like the Update Manager, Software Center?

Answer (score 1):

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

This tells you that another `dpkg` or `apt` command is already running.
Please inspect your running processes with `ps auxw |egrep -e 'apt|dpkg'

- If such a program is running, kill it.
- If really no such program is running, delete the lock file: `sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

For sanity invoke `dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 0):

Run

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get install unsettings`